# React rendering both components defined in ternary conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Render function:

```
if (filteredChildren.length === 0) {
  return <tbody>No projects match filter</tbody>;
}

return (
  TBody({
    children: filteredChildren.map(project => (
      <ProjectsRow key={ project.project_id }>
        {project}
      </ProjectsRow>
    ))
  })
);
```

This code, by the looks of it.. should never return both branches, but yet this is what I see:

[image]

And oddly enough, when I actually have some filtervalue:

[image]

To complete this nonsense, let's simply remove one line from our code.

```
if (filteredChildren.length === 0) {
  // return <tbody>No projects match filter</tbody>; Begone!
}

return (
  TBody({
    children: filteredChildren.map(project => (
      <ProjectsRow key={ project.project_id }>
        {project}
      </ProjectsRow>
    ))
  })
);
```

Now everything works, no doubled up components, but no helpful message when no projects are found:

[image]

UPDATE:

A few parents up where the `filterValue` is state:

```
class FilterCard extends Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { filterValue: `` };
  }

  handleInput = (): void =>
    this.setState({ filterValue: this.refs.filterInput.value });

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <Row>
        <input
          ref="filterInput"
          onChange={this.handleInput}
          type="text"
        />

        { Children.map(children, child => {
          return cloneElement(child, {
            filterValue: this.state.filterValue
          });
        })}
     </Row>
    );
  }
}
```

Direct parent:

```
export default function ProjectsTable({
  sort,
  order,
  router,
  children,
  filterValue
}: ProjectsTableProps): React.Element {
  return (
    <Table>
      <ProjectsColumns sort={ sort } order={ order } />
      <ProjectsRows router={ router } filterValue={ filterValue }>
        { children }
      </ProjectsRows>
    </Table>
  );
}
```

I should try filtering the children in one of the parent components.. no need to pass the filter value down just to filter it there.

Also as a crazy side note, when inspect using Chrome elements panel, that node with the text above the table.... isn't even there!!! Ghost element...!

UPDATE 2:

Filtering in the above component fixes my issue but I would LOVE to know what's causing the error the way I had it before.. I'm guessing React does some weird stuff when working inside table elements.

Working code:

```
export default function ProjectsTable({
  sort,
  order,
  router,
  children,
  filterValue
}: ProjectsTableProps): React.Element {
  const filteredChildren = children.filter(filterProjects(filterValue));

  if (!filteredChildren.length) {
    return <div>No projects.</div>;
  }

  return (
    <Table>
      <ProjectsColumns sort={ sort } order={ order } />
      <ProjectsRows router={ router }>
        { filteredChildren }
      </ProjectsRows>
    </Table>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there a parent component render function that you can post? Also, TBody seems to be a function and not JSX, which would normally throw an error. Can you post the code for that?

Comment: @Mike Updated my answer, and yeah functional components are just functions so you can call them as such, no need for jsx.